# error TS2740: Type 'DocumentChangeAction<{}>[]' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I have a problem with doing a search bar.

My problem is how to get the data from firebase and make it in front end with angular.

I try to make a service to search the name like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class FirebaseService {

 constructor(public db: AngularFirestore) {

 }
   searchUsers(searchValue){
    return this.db.collection('Mot',ref => ref.where('Kurde', '>=', 
   searchValue)
  .where('Kurde', '<=', searchValue + '\uf8ff'))
  .snapshotChanges()
  }
}
```

and my component is like that :

```
  import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../shared/services/firebase.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';



export interface Mot {
  Kurde: string;
  Francais: string;
  Iran:string;
  Turquie:string;
  syrie:string;
  Pro:string;
  Iraq:string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recherche',
  templateUrl: './recherche.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recherche.component.css']
})
export class RechercheComponent implements OnInit {
 Motinfo: Mot = {
   Kurde: '',
   Francais: '',
   Iran:'',
   Turquie:'',
   syrie:'',
   Pro:'',
   Iraq:'',
 };
  constructor( public firebaseService: FirebaseService,
) {

}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  rechercheKurde(kurde) {
    this.firebaseService.searchUsers(kurde)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.Motinfo = result;
      console.log(result)
    })
}
}
```

so it give me an error in the compomnent :

> ERROR in ../../components/recherche/recherche.component.ts(43,7):
>   error TS2740: Type 'DocumentChangeAction<{}>[]' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'Mot': Kurde, Francais, Iran, Turquie,
>   and 3 more.

My database in firebase looks like that:

[image]